# Let user select the number of posts shown per page jquery error

Tags: php, posts, jquery, query

I want the user to be able to chose to display 10, 20, or 30 posts per page.

I found this [Let user change posts per page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63910/let-user-change-posts-per-page) but it doesn't work.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40077395/wordpress-let-user-select-the-number-of-posts-shown-per-page) and implemented it but I get a jquery error. `Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function`

Here is my code: (I'm using Bootstrap 4)

```
<?php

  if( isset($_GET['pageVal']) ) {
    $showposts = esc_sql($_GET['pageVal']);
  } else {
    $showposts = 10;
  }

  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $newsposts = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $showposts,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'category_name' => 'News'
  );
  query_posts($newsposts);
?>
<?php if ( have_posts('newsposts') ) : ?>
<section class="blue">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-start px-sm-4 white-text">
        <span class="font-weight-bold p-2 mr-3">Title Filter</span>
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[wpdreams_ajaxsearchlite]'); ?>
        <span class="font-weight-bold p-2">Display #</span>
        <select id="news-posts-per-page" class="page-select">
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
        </select>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
          $('.page-select').change(function(){
            var checkIndex = window.location.href.indexOf('?');
            if( checkIndex > -1 ){
              var Link = window.location.href.substr(0, checkIndex-1);
              $(location).attr('href', Link+'?page='+$('.page-select').val());
            } else {
              $(location).attr('href', window.location.href+'?page='+$('.page-select').val());
            }
          });

        });
        </script>
        <span class="font-weight-bold pl-1 py-2"><i class="fas fa-sort"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix would be to change the query name; i.e. from `page` to `pageVal`.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
  $('.page-select').change(function(){
    var checkIndex = ( window.location.href || '' ).indexOf('?');
    if( checkIndex > -1 ){
      var Link = window.location.href.substr(0, checkIndex-1);
      $(location).attr('href', Link+'?pageVal='+$('.page-select').val());
    } else {
      $(location).attr('href', window.location.href+'?pageVal='+$('.page-select').val());
    }
  });

});
</script>
```

But I'd use this..:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
  $('.page-select').change(function(){
    var url = window.location.href || '',
      has_q = ( url.indexOf( '?' ) > -1 );

    if ( url.indexOf( '?pageVal=' ) > -1 ) {
      url = url.replace( /\?pageVal=\d+/, '?pageVal=' + this.value );
    } else if ( has_q && url.indexOf( '&pageVal=' ) > -1 ) {
      url = url.replace( /&pageVal=\d+/, '&pageVal=' + this.value );
    } else {
      url = url + ( has_q ? '&' : '?' ) + 'pageVal=' + this.value;
    }

    window.location.href = url;
  });

});
</script>
```

**Additional Note**

I'd also change the `select` to:

```
<select id="news-posts-per-page" class="page-select"><?php
  // List of "posts per page" options.
  $per_pages = [ 10, 20, 30 ];

  foreach ( $per_pages as $n ) {
    $selected = selected( $n, $showposts, false );
    printf( '<option value="%d"%s>%d</option>',
      $n, $selected, $n );
  }
?></select>
```